# locally closed orbits in metric Hausdorff topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, topological-groups, group-actions, positive-characteristic

I learned the following fact from Bruhat and Tits's paper "Homomorphismes “abstraits” de groupes algebriques simples" Section 3.18 that

Let $k$ be a local field. Suppose that a $k$-group $H$ acts $k$-rationaly on a $k$-variety $M$ and $x$ is an element of $M(k)$ such that the map $h\mapsto hx$ for $h\in H$ of the group $H$ onto the orbit $Hx$ is separable . Then $H(k)x$ is locally closed in $M(k)$ with respect to metric Hausdorff topology.

Separable means its differential is surjective. I think any morphism is separable in characteristic 0. I have seen some examples for which the action is not separable, but all orbit are locally closed with respect to metric Hausdorff topology.

**Q1**: Is there a weaker (than separable) condition to ensure that all orbits are locally closed?

**Q2**: Do we know any examples for which there exists a non-locally closed orbit with respect to metric Hausdorff topology in positive characteristic case? It will be more interesting to have such action, which is also linear.

---

Thanks to user81562, I think we have the following:

**If $F$ is a non-archimedean local field and $X$ algebraic variety defined over $F$. If $G$ is a linear algebraic $F$-group and $G\times X \rightarrow X$ is $F$-rational action. Then the action is constructive see Thm A on page 57 and in particular, all its orbits are locally closed (see proposition 6.8 c in http://www.math1.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/B-Zel-RepsGL-Usp.pdf).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orbits are always locally closed for the Hausdorff topology, even in positive characteristic. This follows from the appendix in the paper of Bernstein and Zelevinskii, [Representations of the group GL(n,F), where F is a local non-Archimedean field.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=425030) 
Uspehi Mat. Nauk 31 (1976), no. 3(189), 5–70.

Comment: http://www.math1.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/B-Zel-RepsGL-Usp.pdf

Comment: This generalizes to the case where $k$ is a henselian valued field such that $\widehat{k}/k$ is separable, where $\widehat{k}$ is the completion of $k$. The latter condition is not needed if the orbit map is separable (or equivalently the stabilizer of $x$ is smooth). See my paper with Gabber and Gille: http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2014-5/2014-5-025.pdf

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks a lot. It is very interesting paper. Do you have an answer to my another relevant question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261893/are-all-stabilizer-groups-of-the-co-adjoint-action-smooth?